# Classic ASP on IIS 7 - Need Uploader Component

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic

Moved from IIS6 to IIS7 (Windows 2008 Server 64 bit).
I'm looking for an upload component to use with my Classic ASP.
Is there some .Net code that does this?

Comment: IIS is not relevant, also removed irrelevant .NET tags. You can use a pure ASP script I wrote some while ago, it's available [here](http://forums.aspfree.com/code-bank-54/pure-asp-upload-script-additional-features-94647.html). While focusing on images and detecting their size it's just optional and you can upload all kinds of files just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in Classic ASP in code only without using a component. There are several version sof this code but [Free ASP Upload](http://www.freeaspupload.net/) seems a popular choice.